# after deployment react project is not working

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I have made a simple hacker-news project. It has simple functionalities like search ,redirect to next page etc.
It works perfectly fine on loacalhost but after I deployed it none of the functionalities work what should I do.

This is my github repo: https://github.com/yashkr18/Hacker-News.

This is the deployed version: https://6131026147f71d1505e11cb8--naughty-lewin-cc520d.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to call http from an HTTPS:

> Table.js:40 Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://6131026147f71d1505e11cb8--naughty-lewin-cc520d.netlify.app/'
> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
> 'http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=a'. This request has been
> blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Change your urls to https and it will work just fine. I put it in a sandbox and tested:  https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-paper-bdy7j?file=/components/Table.js